# Retrieve characters like Ä, ê from MySQL using Flask-Alchemy

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't retrieve characters like ä and ê from MySQL by using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I am trying to build a website using Flask, Flask_SQLAlchemy and MySQL (5.5.3). I have taken one course in programming (Python) and the rest is self thought so I would be very happy if you could be as detailed as possible in your answers, very thankful for any advice!

This link was slightly helpful, but I have problems with retrieving not storing:
[Flask_SQLAlchemy, MySQL, store Swedish characters å, ä, ö?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707867/flask-sqlalchemy-mysql-store-swedish-characters-%C3%A5-%C3%A4-%C3%B6)

```
(competeEnv) C:\>conda list
 # packages in environment at C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3.1\envs\competeEnv:
 #
click                     6.6                      py27_0
flask                     0.11.1                   py27_0
Flask-SQLAlchemy          2.1                       <pip>
itsdangerous              0.24                     py27_0
jinja2                    2.8                      py27_1
markupsafe                0.23                     py27_2
mysql-python              1.2.5                    py27_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py27_0
python                    2.7.12                        0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py27_1
sqlalchemy                1.1.4                    py27_0
vs2008_runtime            9.00.30729.1                  2
werkzeug                  0.11.11                  py27_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0
(competeEnv) C:\>
```

Here is the code in testAlchemy.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:myPassword@myServer/firstdb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=True
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET'] = 'utf8mb4'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__='users'
    id=db.Column('iduser', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column('column_name', db.String(193))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name.decode('utf-8')

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()

president1=Users('Obama')
president2=Users('Trump')
db.session.add(president1)
db.session.add(president2)
db.session.commit()
```

Here should be some hints..

```
(competeEnv) C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3.1\envs>python
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13)[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.

>>> from testAlchemy import Users, db
>>> db.session.add(Users('Federer'))
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> Users.query.all()
[Obama, Trump, Federer]
>>> db.session.add(Users(u'ä'))
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> Users.query.all()
[Obama, Trump, Federer, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "testAlchemy.py", line 23, in __repr__
    return self.name.decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3.1\envs\envNew\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Comment: I test code on Linux and have no problem - but Linux use `utf-8` in all system - especially in console - and Windows may use different encodings in console - mostly `cp1250` (`windows-1250`)

Comment: I think you may have a point! (I'm not an expert so can't say you're right either unfortunately :) ) However, when I just add one more line of code in my testAlchemy.py file: print('ä') and then import it as before I get: **SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file testAlchemy.py on line 49, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details** So is that related? I don't get that problem by just typing print('ä') in the console however.. Do you have any suggestions on what I could do? :)

Comment: you may have to manually encode text to `cp1250` (or other `cp125x`) `print( 'ä'.encode('cp1250') )` - check also `print( sys.getdefaultencoding() )` it shows what encoding will be used if you don't use encoding manually.

Comment: Adding: **#!/usr/bin/env python, # -- coding: utf-8 --**; in the beginning of the file allowed me to import the file containing the print(u'ä') statement! When I tried print( sys.getdefaultencoding() ) in the .py file or in the console itself it always returned ascii, however, I don't know what to do with that :(

Comment: if `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `ascii` then it means that `print()`  use `encode('ascii')` as default and you have to manually use `.encode('other_encoding')` before you print text with native characters - ie `print( sometext.encode('cp1250') )` or in your class `return self.name.encode('cp1250')`. But maybe you have to use different  encoding, not `cp1250` but `cp1251`, `cp1252`, etc. or `cp852` - I don't use Windows so I can't help more - encodings in Polish language http://imgur.com/aWIDjwT

Comment: BTW: [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .