# Get data from MySql with RIDE

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm trying to read data from a MySql database. Everything is correct except when I have to receive words with an accent or the character 'ñ'

I have reviewed the collation of my database. I have it configured in utf8_unicode_ci in the table and in the column.

I use python 2.7.8 and I have tried to decode and unicode and I can not write well the result of the tables. I always get:

Baño -> Ba\xf1o

Lámina -> L\xe1mina

I launch the query from RIDE (1.5.2.1) under Windows 10.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you "receiving" the text?  `ñ`, when encoded as hex `e1` is encoded as `latin1`.  (Actually any of cp1250, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5, but probably latin1, since that is the old default for MySQL.)

If you actually have `e1` in the client, then tell MySQL that you have latin1.  It is OK to have the database tables set to utf8 -- MySQL will transliterate as you do the stores/fetches.

It would be better to have utf8 everywhere.

Here are my notes on Python:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python
Note that that section ends with a link to an issue with the old Python 2.7, which you seem to be using: [Flask_SQLAlchemy, MySQL, store Swedish characters å, ä, ö?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707867/flask-sqlalchemy-mysql-store-swedish-characters-%C3%A5-%C3%A4-%C3%B6/40708131#40708131)

Comment: Thank you very much, the following link has been very useful: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Here I saw that I had to add dbcharset = 'utf8' in the connection. With this the problem has been solved.

Now I receive correctly MySQL characters with accents and with 'ñ'.

Many thanks!

Comment: @Marta79 - Glad the link helped.  Alas, the link is a jumble of things.  Did you see anything 'wrong'?  Should I rearrange it?  Other critique?  (I've never used Python.)